# I am triying to install qiime2-2023.2 from Miniconda3, but i get this error

Tags: package, windows-subsystem-for-linux, miniconda, qiime

Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

```
   File "/mnt/e/curso_qiime2/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 16, in __call__                              |  23%
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/e/curso_qiime2/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main.py", line 49, in do_call                                    |  48%
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)                                                                                          
  File "/mnt/e/curso_qiime2/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/notices/core.py", line 123, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/e/curso_qiime2/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main_create.py", line 163, in execute
    result[installer_type] = installer.install(
  File "/mnt/e/curso_qiime2/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_env/installers/conda.py", line 62, in install
    unlink_link_transaction.execute()
  File "/mnt/e/curso_qiime2/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 350, in execute
    self.verify()
  File "/mnt/e/curso_qiime2/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 83, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/mnt/e/curso_qiime2/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 306, in verify
    exceptions = self._verify(self.prefix_setups, self.prefix_action_groups)
  File "/mnt/e/curso_qiime2/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 812, in _verify
    for exc in self.verify_executor.map(
  File "/mnt/e/curso_qiime2/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 560, in map
    yield func(thing)
  File "/mnt/e/curso_qiime2/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 589, in _verify_individual_level
    error_result = axn.verify()
  File "/mnt/e/curso_qiime2/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/path_actions.py", line 425, in verify
    source_size_in_bytes = getsize(self.source_full_path)
  File "/mnt/e/curso_qiime2/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
OSError: [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/mnt/e/curso_qiime2/miniconda3/pkgs/ncurses-6.3-h27087fc_1/share/terminfo/N/NCR260VT300WPP'
```

I already update the conda packages but the error persist. I dont know if this has someting to do with the directory in which miniconda is installed, i installed it in a non system disc (D:), its an internal disc